# Code snippet PHP, end of file expected, where am i wrong?

Tags: php, json, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I dont know where am i wrong... pls help me. I've been searching the internet for an hour and I can't find a solution.
[image: PHP]

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?more_on=xron.net). People here regard that as evil. Post the actual code which should be reproducible. Show your error, sow your effort in trying to solve the error.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd go as far as "evil", but images of text are certainly _unhelpful_. They make your question harder to read, harder to answer, and less useful to future readers. In this case, you haven't even positioned the screen properly before taking the screenshot - we can't see line 1.

Answer (score 0):

On the line under the comment block, change `}` to `},` (add a comma).

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: did you do this change on line 19? Did the error change? Please put all details within your question, so we can see the whole "picture"